# Virtual Machine Got Frozen on start of installing FreeBSD, on CentOS6.3 KVM

Tags: virtualization, centos, freebsd, linux-kvm

**Problem description:**

In the installation section, after I entered the virt-install command with proper arguments(shown below) to build the virtual hardware configuration, and connected to the vm console with vnc, I got a no-respond screen staying on the welcome of installment menu with the vcpu occupied 100%, so I cannot even take the next step on installation.

Whatever I adjusted the virt-install arguments, specified them or using default by omitting, it just didn't work and repeated the malfunction. But the KVM enviroment has no problem when I install any other vm using linux distribution like centos or opensuse.

So I want to know what's wrong with my freebsd vm configuration, or is it a hardware problem, e.g. referring to the specific CPU quality? And I want to get help on how to fix it.

**Hardware environment:**

Intel i5-3570K
16G RAM
128G SSD Plextor M5P
2T HDD Westdigital
Intel 1G ethernet card
Atheros 1G ethernet card

**Software environment:**

CentOS 6.3 Basic Server
libvirt up-to-date
KVM up-to-date
all commands run as root.

**some of arguments I tried:**

```
virt-install \
--name freebsd9
--virt-type kvm \ # still didn't work when omitted.
--ram 4096 \ # no effect even I adjust the ram size bigger or smaller.
--vcpus=1 \ # if I use two vcpus, one is 100% occupied, and the other is free.
--cpu host \ 
# still didn't work when omitted or modified to sandybridge or whatever kind 
  in xml file using command "virsh edit freebsd9".
--disk path=.../freebsd9.img,size=10,type=qcow2 \
--cdrom $install_cdrom_path \ 
# using installation iso file, freebsd 8 or 9, neither is ok.
--network bridge=br0,model=e1000,mac="52:54:00:..." \
--vnc \
--os-type=unix \
--os-variant=freebsd8 \
```

Comment: Hi, the command virt-install, if successful, should have created an XML file in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/freebsd9.xml` (if you sticked to the name freebsd9). Could you give us access to this file (via a gist on Github or via pastebin, etc.)?

Comment: @Huygens thank you for your kindly advice and sorry for replying so late. I've transferred to debian platform and no need for that now.